# Pie layout using multiple values within a single object

Tags: d3.js

I have an array of objects returned in JSON output via an AJAX call, like so:

```
[{"applicants":"100","successful_applicants":"50","role":"program advisor"},
{"applicants":"120","successful_applicants":"80","role":"academic counselor"},
{"applicants":"100","successful_applicants":"50","role":"mathematics tutor"}]
```

which I am passing in as a variable called *data*.

I am currently calling the d3.pie layout like so:

```
$.post('search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data) {
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius);
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .value(function (d) {return d.successful_applicants });
```

and then after creating an svg for each object in the returned array, I append as follows...

```
    var arcs = group
               .append("path")
               .attr("d", arc)
               .attr("fill", "red")
               .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
               .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
               .attr("transform", "translate(" + (box_width + stroke_width)/2 + "," + (box_height + stroke_width)/2 + ")");
}
```

I wish to use d3.js to generate one pie chart per object in the returned array displaying two slices: showing *successful*`_*applicants* as a percentage of *applicants*. In simplified terms this would be two data points "successful applicants" and "unsuccessful applicants", the sum of these two data points should generate a complete circle.

How can I have d3 dynamically generate the required array of "successful applicants" and "unsuccessful applicants"? Is the answer within the .value() function? The best I am able to do so far is to draw one value from each object in the array as an arc/slice (as would be apparent from the line...

```
.value(function (d)  { return d.successful_applicants});
```

Comment: Its actually an array of objects. So when you return your data assign your data to a variable and then you should be able to access if just like you would any array or object. array[object.key]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I haven't been clever enough to understand it though, so I've rewritten my question in hope that it might elicit an answer more suited to my level (lol/sigh). Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course this is possible. You would simply create several pie chart layouts with different `.value()` functions or, if you prefer that, have one pie chart layout and pass in different subsets of the data as values. In either case, you would draw the actual chart in the same way.

To be clear, there is nothing in D3 that will give you several charts out of the box. You will have to create/arrange them yourself, but there is nothing that limits a given function to be applied to one chart only.

For example, in addition to

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function (d) {return d.successful_applicants });
```

you could have

```
var pie1 = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function (d) {return d.applicants });
```

Then you can use this new variable in the same way as the original one for another pie chart.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am struggling to follow it (perhaps obvious by the delay in replying). I've included more of my code in an edit/rewrite of the question above. I'd love it if you could expand upon your suggestion of how to pass in different subsets of the data as values into the one pie chart layout. Thanks!